# ReactJs: Move data fetching code or side effects to componentDidUpdate

Tags: reactjs

I got following warning, but I do not know which data change it means, do you have any idea?

```
Warning: componentWillReceiveProps has been renamed, and is not recommended for use. See react-unsafe-component-lifecycles for details.

* Move data fetching code or side effects to componentDidUpdate.
* If you're updating state whenever props change, refactor your code to use memoization techniques or move it to static getDerivedStateFromProps. Learn more at: 
* Rename componentWillReceiveProps to UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps to suppress this warning in non-strict mode. In React 17.x, only the UNSAFE_ name will work. To rename all deprecated lifecycles to their new names, you can run `npx react-codemod rename-unsafe-lifecycles` in your project source folder.

Please update the following components: t
```

code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import FacebookLogin from "react-facebook-login";
import Menu from "@material-ui/core/Menu";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";

// import this
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

// make this
const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2)
  },
  title: {
    flexGrow: 1
  }
});

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    accessToken: "",
    isLoggedIn: false,
    userID: "",
    name: "",
    email: "",
    picture: ""
  };

  responseFacebook = response => {
    this.setState({
      accessToken: response.accessToken,
      isLoggedIn: true,
      userID: response.userID,
      name: response.name,
      email: response.email,
      picture: response.picture.data.url
    });
  };

  handleClick = event => this.setState({ anchorEl: event.currentTarget });
  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ anchorEl: undefined });
  };
  handleCloseAndLogOut = () => {
    this.setState({ anchorEl: undefined });
    this.setState({ isLoggedIn: undefined });
    this.setState({ userID: undefined });
    this.setState({ name: undefined });
    this.setState({ email: undefined });
    this.setState({ picture: undefined });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    document.title = "Tiket.hu";
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    // What put here?
  }

  render() {
    let fbContent;
    let listContent;
    //const { anchorEl } = this.state;
    if (this.state.isLoggedIn) {
      fbContent = (
        <div>
          <Button
            aria-controls="simple-menu"
            aria-haspopup="true"
            onClick={this.handleClick}
          >
            {this.state.name}
          </Button>
          <Menu
            id="simple-menu"
            anchorEl={this.status.anchorEl}
            keepMounted
            open={Boolean(this.status.anchorEl)}
            onClose={this.handleClose}
          >
            <MenuItem onClick={this.handleCloseAndLogOut}>Log out</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>
              Switch mode to Release
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>My tickets</MenuItem>
          </Menu>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      let fbAppId;
      if (
        window.location.hostname === "localhost" ||
        window.location.hostname === "127.0.0.1"
      )
        fbAppId = "402670860613108";
      else fbAppId = "2526636684068727";
      fbContent = (
        <FacebookLogin
          appId={fbAppId}
          autoLoad={true}
          fields="name,email,picture"
          onClick={this.componentClicked}
          callback={this.responseFacebook}
        />
      );
    }
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <AppBar position="static">
          <Toolbar>
            <Typography variant="h6" className={this.props.classes.title}>
              Tiket.hu
            </Typography>
            <Button color="inherit">Search</Button>
            <Button color="inherit">Basket</Button>
            {fbContent}
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
        {listContent}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(App);
```

Comment: that error it's not caused by your component. Maybe one of your dependencies use componentDidMount

Answer (score 1):

The component you show doesn't have a componentWillReceiveProps, so it's not the problem. The error message includes this:

> Please update the following components: t

So we're looking for a component named `t`. If you have one with that name, that's the one you'd need to fix. But my guess is that's not one of your components, but rather one that's being used indirectly by one of the libraries you've imported. If that's the case, only the library creator will be able to fix this, and you'd then import a new version of their code.

This warning will not stop your code from running with current versions of react, but it will prevent you from upgrading to version 17 of react (which doesn't exist yet)